# what is the reason for these data variables declaration differention in C

Tags: c, c99

**unsigned short upper limit is 65535 and more than this number revolve to start with 0;**

```
unsigned short a = 65535;
printf("%d", a);
```

a = 65535

```
unsigned short a = 65536;
printf("%d", a);
```

a = 0

```
unsigned short a = 65537;
printf("%d", a);
```

a = 1

etc.

**but... when the declaration with calculation (pow, multiplication, addition etc.), the number not pass the upper limit.**

```
unsigned short a = pow(2, 16) - 1;
printf("%d", a);
```

a = 65535

```
unsigned short a = pow(2, 16);
printf("%d", a);
```

a = 65535

```
unsigned short a = pow(2, 17);
printf("%d", a);
```

a = 65535
... etc.

**What is the reason for this situation?**

Comment: @Cheatah it is not the problem here. Most modern compilers even with -O0 will not call pow at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use the correct format specifier if you want to print unsigned values:

```
printf("%hu", a);
```

2. `unsigned short a = pow(2, 16);`the value 65536 (or larger) does not fit the `unsigned short`. A per @JohnBollinger commant the assignment of the out of range floating value is **undefined**, and two different compilers or even the same depending on the optimization level or other options may produce different results:

https://godbolt.org/z/TG9z8xhaG

```
gcc - 65535
clang - 0
```